# contains method doesn't work properly

Tags: java

I tried to use the `contains` method to search for a word in a sentence but it only works for the first word in the sentence.

For example when searching for 'Shakira' in "liked Shakira's photo" my program cannot find it.  On the other hand, searching for 'liked' in the same sentence works.

This is the code I'm using:

```
package fules;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class fule {

    public static int i,x,n,k,ba,sh,fe;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  {

        File s=new File("C:/Users/taha/Desktop/tt.in");
        Scanner m=new Scanner(s);
        fule obj=new fule();
        i=m.nextInt();//test case
        n=m.nextInt();
        k=m.nextInt();
        for (int l=0;l<6;l++){
            boolean q=contains((m.next()),("taha"));
            if(q) {
                ba++;
            }
            boolean w=contains((m.next()),("Shakira"));
            if(w)
                sh++;
        }
        boolean e=contains((m.next()),("Fegla"));
        if(e) {
            fe++;
        }

        System.out.println("ba="+ba+" sh="+sh+" fe="+fe);
        m.close();
    }

    static boolean contains (String s1,String s2)
    {
        return s1.contains(s2);
    }
}
```

and this is 
the inputs in( tt.in)

```
1
6 2
liked Badr's photo
liked Shakira's photo
liked Badr's photo
liked Fegla's photo
liked Shakira's photo
commented on Shakira's photo
```

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Trust me, it works perfectly fine. You're just using it wrong. Your code is unpleasant to read because of naming and formatting, I would advise you to fix this first.

Comment: Is this decompiled code, or are you just trying to confuse us?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the input with the `next()` method which `Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner`. Therefore you only read the first word of the sentence.

Try to replace `next()` with `nextLine()`.

And if you want to compare the same String against multiple patterns, store that String in a variable. Currently each of your calls to `contains()` reads a new String from the scanner.

You should write something like this :

```
        String input = m.nextLine();
        boolean q=contains(input,"Badr");
        if(q)
        {
            ba++;
        }
        boolean w=contains(input,"Shakira");
        if(w)
            sh++;
        }
        boolean e=contains(input,"Fegla");
        if(e)
        {
            fe++;
        }
```

This would find "Shakira" in "liked Shakira's photo".

Of course, there are more efficient ways to write the same code.

```
        String input = m.nextLine();
        if (input.contains("Badr"))
            ba++;
        if (input.contains("Shakira"))
            sh++;
        if (input.contains("Fegla"))
            fe++;
```

Comment: @TahaAlmasri I suggest you print the input String, so that you are sure you are calling `contains` on what you think you are.

Comment: i tried to put String input ="liked Badr's photo" and it found the name, but it can't read it from the file :( !!! i mean i can't write:  String input =m.nextLine();

Comment: @TahaAlmasri maybe you should get rid of your `m.nextInt()` statements. Is there any purpose to them?

Comment: yes i for number of cases, n for number of likes and comments ,k for the most friends whom interact with you 
even if you remove them you will not find a solution

Comment: @TahaAlmasri What does your input file look like? Are you managing to read anything from it?